# js syntax error: missing ) after argument

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure what is wrong.

```
cell1.innerHTML = '<a onclick="displaySteps(\'' + temp +  '\')" id="testSteps"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-custom fa-clickable"></i></a>' + "  N/A";
```

Executing the above line always gives me the following error

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Learn More]
```

Comment: If anyone has a better way to achieve this please let me know.

Comment: Well, what's the value of `temp`?

Comment: Try putting the ' ' in the temp variable so you don't have to escape it by \'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a quote in `temp` that's causing a syntax error in the function call.

Rather than creating an `onclick` attribute, it would be safer to add the event listener with code.

```
cell1.innerHTML = '<a o id="testSteps"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-custom fa-clickable"></i></a>' + "  N/A";
document.getElementById("testSteps").addEventListener("click", (function(temp) {
    displaySteps(temp);
})(temp));
```

Comment: I used your solution. The other answers still gave me the same error. The issue was that I have no idea what the temp variable holds as it is sent from my server. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `missing ) after argument list error` and the only function call in the above code is `displaySteps`, I would assume there is something within the rendered value of the `test` variable that's causing it. Try logging the value of `test` to ensure it doesn't contain any stray `)` or unescaped characters

Also, a cleaner way to do this would be with [`Template Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)-

```
const icon = `<i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-custom fa-clickable"></i>`
const renderDisplayFn = (arg) => `'displaySteps(${arg})'`

cell1.innerHTML = `<a onclick=${renderDisplayFn(test)} id='testSteps'>${icon}</a> N/A`
```

Comment: Just for information: Some browsers throw error when they encounter tilde(`) being used for string. for eg Safari and IE.

Answer (score 1):

```
cell1.innerHTML = `<a onclick="displaySteps('${temp}')" id="testSteps"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-custom fa-clickable"></i></a> N/A`;
```